# MySQL JOIN two tables and get latest result

Tags: mysql, performance, schema, optimization, query-performance

I want to JOIN two tables and get the latest result from each one of those two in a single table. I'm kind of concerned about speed too since tables are growing kinda fast. Close to 60-70k records a day. Later on i will go into partitioning but that is another issue. Now i have a main table with the `devices` info.

```
+--------+-----------+---------+
|     id |    Name   | type    |
+--------+-----------+---------+
|      1 | Oh        | A       |
|      2 | This      | A       |
|      3 | Is        | B       |
|      4 | Hard      | A       |
+--------+-----------+---------+
```

According to the type they have some data in different tables
Type A is

```
+--------+-----------+------------------+---------+---------+
|     id | device_id |   stats_time     | status  |  noise  |
+--------+-----------+------------------+---------+---------+
|      1 | 1         | 2012-10-23 07:50 | foo     |   10    |
|      2 | 1         | 2012-10-23 16:59 | bar     |   12    |
|      3 | 2         | 2012-10-23 15:11 | bar     |   0     |
|      4 | 4         | 2012-10-23 23:23 | foo     |   25    |
+--------+-----------+------------------+---------+---------+
```

Type B is

```
+--------+-----------+------------------+---------+---------+
|     id | device_id |   stats_time     | status  |  signal |
+--------+-----------+------------------+---------+---------+
|      1 | 3         | 2012-10-23 04:50 | foo     |  1000   |
|      2 | 3         | 2012-10-23 05:59 | bar     |  450    |
|      3 | 3         | 2012-10-23 09:11 | bar     |  980    |
|      4 | 3         | 2012-10-23 10:23 | foo     |   0     |
+--------+-----------+------------------+---------+---------+
```

I've been busting my head for a query to end up with something like this

```
+--------+-----------+------------------+---------+---------+---------+
|     id | device_id |   stats_time     | status  |  signal |   noise |
+--------+-----------+------------------+---------+---------+---------+
|      1 | 1         | 2012-10-23 16:59 | bar     |  12     |         |
|      2 | 2         | 2012-10-23 15:11 | bar     |  0      |         |
|      3 | 3         | 2012-10-23 10:23 | foo     |         |    0    |
|      4 | 4         | 2012-10-23 23:23 | foo     |  25     |         |
+--------+-----------+------------------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Using the below query is not good since i get two columns of `stats_time`

```
SELECT devices.id AS id, A.stats_time , B.stats_time
FROM devices 
LEFT JOIN A ON devices.id = A.device_id 
LEFT JOIN B ON devices.id = B.device_id 
GROUP BY devices.id
```

Before i ended up using different tables for the device types i used to get the results with the following but ended up going real slow

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM A
    ORDER BY stats_time DESC, id ASC
) AS d
RIGHT JOIN devices ON A.device_id = devices.id
GROUP BY devices.id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see it as 2 steps:

1. Build tables with just the latest signal (or noise) for each device
2. `JOIN` or `UNION` the two tables.

Step 1 is a variant of [groupwise max](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max):

```
SELECT  device_id, stats_time, status, noise -- The desired columns
    FROM  ( SELECT  @prev := '' ) init
    JOIN  ( SELECT
                device_id != @prev AS first, -- `device_id` is the 'GROUP BY'
                @prev := device_id,          -- the 'GROUP BY'
                device_id, stats_time, status, noise -- Also the desired columns
            FROM  TableA -- The table
            ORDER BY  device_id  DESC, -- The 'GROUP BY'
                      stats_time DESC  -- to get latest
      ) x
    WHERE  first;
```

This may be beneficial to performance:

```
INDEX(device_id, stats_time)
```

Ditto for `TableB` and `signal`.  Manually run them to see if I got them right.

Your example does not show a case where both `signal` and `noise` exist for the same `device_id`.  I will assume that is really the case, hence `UNION`:

Step 2:

```
SELECT device_id, stats_time, status, signal, noise
    FROM
    ( SELECT device_id, stats_time, status, signal, '' AS noise
        ... (the rest of the signal query)
    )
    UNION ALL
    ( SELECT device_id, stats_time, status, '' AS signal, noise
        ... (the rest of the noise query)
    );
```

Answer (score 3):

I stated in the above comments that this seems to be a case of a supertype-subtype relationship but, since changing your database structure may be a decision that lies outside of the scope of this question, I am going to focus on offering a solution for your current situation.

Then, after a couple of edits, I decided to include some `DDL` statements and a brief description of my assumptions about your database structure, hoping that in this way my answer and its involved queries will be more easily comprehended.

## Understanding of the situation and hypothetical `DDL`

As I percive the scenario, `type_a` and `type_b` may be two different kinds of `reading` or `measurement` that you are collecting for each `device.`

This way, although I am not completely sure of the meaning of the `type_a.type_a_id` and `type_b.type_b_id` columns, I assume that they are some sort of `sequential_number` or `row_number` or `record_identifier` in each respective table. Likewise, the columns `type_a.stats_time` and `type_b.stats_time` are the exact points in time when a `device` posts some sort of `reading`.

I have also assumed that `type_a.device_id` and `type_b.device_id` are FOREIGN KEYS that make reference to the `device` table that, in turn, has the column `device.device_id` being used as some kind of `sequential_number` or `row_number` or `record_identifier` that you have defined as PRIMARY KEY.

Having described my understanding of the state of affairs, please note that I am **not** suggesting that this is the optimal structure (since, naturally, I am not familiar with the real scenario, it may lack normalization, integrity, etc.), I am just making some assumptions based on the data samples and queries that you have presented, in order to deliver a possible solution for your specific situation. So, here is the speculative `DDL`:

```
CREATE TABLE device
(
    device_id INT      NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name      CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    type      CHAR(1)  NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (device_id),
    UNIQUE INDEX uix_name (name) 
);

CREATE TABLE type_a
(
    type_a_id  INT      NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    device_id  INT      NOT NULL ,
    stats_time DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `status`   CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    noise      INT      NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (type_a_id),
   CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY fk_type_a_device (device_id) 
   REFERENCES device(device_id),
   UNIQUE INDEX `uix_device_id_and_stats_time` (device_id, stats_time)
);

CREATE TABLE type_b
(
    type_b_id  INT      NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    device_id  INT      NOT NULL,
    stats_time DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `status`   CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    `signal`   INT      NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (type_b_id),
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY fk_type_b_device (device_id) 
    REFERENCES device(device_id),
    UNIQUE INDEX `uix_device_id_and_stats_time` (device_id, stats_time)
);

-- Some ‘device’ INSERTS...

INSERT INTO device (name, type) VALUES ('First device', 'A');
INSERT INTO device (name, type) VALUES ('Second device', 'A');

-- ... And then, some ‘type_a’ and ‘type_b’ INSERTS 
-- in order to have some sample data for retrieving.

INSERT INTO type_a (device_id, stats_time, `status`, noise) 
VALUES (1, STR_TO_DATE('06/01/2015 08:10:01 AM', '%c/%e/%Y %r'), 'Foo', 123);

INSERT INTO type_a (device_id, stats_time, `status`, noise) 
VALUES (1, STR_TO_DATE('04/04/2015 03:07:34 PM', '%c/%e/%Y %r'), 'Bar', 456);

INSERT INTO type_b (device_id, stats_time, `status`, `signal`) 
VALUES (2, STR_TO_DATE('03/04/2015 02:08:15 PM', '%c/%e/%Y %r'), 'Boo', 789);

INSERT INTO type_b (device_id, stats_time, `status`, `signal`) 
VALUES (2, STR_TO_DATE('05/07/2015 04:03:12 PM', '%c/%e/%Y %r'), 'Far', 852);
```

## Initial proposal

And then, here is my first submited query which, while keeping the original idea, has been reformatted and adapted to the `DDL` structure that was added later:

```
SELECT DE.device_id,
       COALESCE(TA.type_a_id, TB.type_b_id)   AS type_id,
       DE.name,
       DE.type,    
       COALESCE(TA.stats_time, TB.stats_time) AS stats_time,
       COALESCE(TA.status, TB.status)         AS `status`,
       COALESCE(TA.noise, 0)                  AS noise,
       COALESCE(TB.signal, 0)                 AS `signal`
  FROM device            DE
  LEFT OUTER JOIN type_a TA
    ON TA.device_id    = DE.device_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN type_b TB
    ON TB.device_id    = DE.device_id
ORDER BY stats_time DESC;
```

As you can see, I am using the [COALESCE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) function that only if the column `type_a.stats_time` contains a `NULL` value, then ‘prints’ the value of the column `type_b.stats_time`, and works in a similar way for the `type_a.status` and `type_b.status` columns.

## Subsequent proposal

### First method

Now, having reread your question and after some comment interactions, I understand that what you actually want is to **obtain a single result set containing only two rows** —one row including columns corresponding to the latest `type_a.stats_time` value and one row holding columns related to the latest `type_b.stats_time` value—. Therefore I suggest you the following query that also retrieves data from the `DDL` proposed above:

```
(SELECT DE.device_id,
        TA.type_a_id  AS type_id,
        DE.name,
        DE.type,      
        TA.stats_time AS stats_time,
        TA.status,
        TA.noise,
        NULL          AS `signal`
   FROM device DE
   JOIN type_a TA
     ON TA.device_id  = DE.device_id
  WHERE TA.stats_time = (SELECT MAX(stats_time) 
                           FROM type_a))

UNION

(SELECT DE.device_id,
        TB.type_b_id  AS type_id,
        DE.name,
        DE.type,      
        TB.stats_time AS stats_time,
        TB.status,
        NULL          AS noise,
        TB.signal
   FROM device DE
   JOIN type_b TB
     ON TB.device_id  = DE.device_id
  WHERE TB.stats_time = (SELECT MAX(stats_time) 
                           FROM type_b))

ORDER BY stats_time DESC;
```

Note the use of the [UNION](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) operator, which in serves the purpose of **combining in one single result set** the latest row of `type_a` (based on the newest `stats_time` column value, obtained via the [MAX()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_max) function within a subquery in the WHERE clause) with the latest row in `type_b` (likewise, based on the newest `stats_time` column value, also obtained through the MAX() function within a subquery in the WHERE clause).

### Second method

You can also try with this alternate query, which sorts each one of the combined result sets based on the `stats_time` column in each respective SELECT statement using the [ORDER BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html) and [LIMIT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/limit-optimization.html) clauses.

```
(SELECT DE.device_id,
        TA.type_a_id  AS type_id,
        DE.name,
        DE.type,      
        TA.stats_time AS stats_time,
        TA.status,
        TA.noise,
        NULL          AS `signal`
   FROM device DE
   JOIN type_a TA
     ON TA.device_id = DE.device_id
  ORDER BY TA.stats_time DESC LIMIT 1)

UNION

(SELECT DE.device_id,
        TB.type_b_id  AS type_id,
        DE.name,
        DE.type,      
        TB.stats_time AS stats_time,
        TB.status,
        NULL          AS noise,
        TB.signal
   FROM device DE
   JOIN type_b TB
     ON TB.device_id = DE.device_id
  ORDER BY TB.stats_time DESC LIMIT 1)

ORDER BY stats_time DESC;
```

Once you compare the performance of all the suggested methods, it will be easy to define which one is the best for your needs. Also, if one of them solves your problem, then you can set it up as a `VIEW`, this way future data retrieval will be easier to obtain.

About the speed performance aspect of your queries, you may start refining such matters by paying special attention to the indexes definition in the apropiate columns, e.g. `type_a.stats_time` and `type_b.stats_time`.

Comment: Hello again and thank you for the time you have put into this. 

I found out from the above that the query that works and kinda-solves it is the first one. I'm still playing around though, although now what is missing from that it returns all the results. A simple `GROUP BY DE.id` solved this but the query takes around 25 seconds going through 800k rows. Is that normal ?

Comment: What if i add another column at the `devices` table and keep there the last inserted `type_a` or `type_b` stats id ? And simple run another query since i'll already know which one is last ?

Comment: @Teris L It’s my pleasure. In my opinion, 800 000 rows is not extraordinary by any means, so 25 seconds is not normal and must be improved, which is what you are up to. It would be really helpful to see your `DDL` definition (maybe a similar one, since your original structure may not be published because of confidentiality reasons), thus, by having well-defined situation, I might be able to help you polishing the details that are slowing down the data retrieval.

Comment: Personally, I do not recommend you to add the column with the last inserted ‘`stats`’ value to the `device` table, since you would be denormalizing the structure and adding unnecesary redundancy. If you do so, everytime that a new `type.stats` row is inserted you also need to update the respective `device`, and since the last `type_a` or `type_b` are already contained in the database, such situation would be needless. You have to make use of other means for improving this performance issue. If you are willing to post the mentioned `DDL`, let me know and I’d be glad to continue helping.